# How to use AWS SDK v2.4.7 to authenticate end user via external provider (e.g., Google)?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm in the process of integrating AWS Cognito for managing authentication and user data in my iOS 9 app using Swift with the AWS iOS SDK v2.4.7. However, I can't find a clear example of how to do this. I've got the Google Sign-In working (i.e., I can successfully get an ID token from Google), but I'm not sure how I can use this to authenticated with AWS. I've created an identity pool and user role with the correct permissions. My problem seems to be in passing this token to Cognito for authentication on AWS's end.

The [code snippet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/google.html) provided in the AWS guide still uses the deprecated methods of the pre-2.4.0 SDK. I haven't found an example of the new best practice. To make matters a bit more confusing, AWS's [Authentication Flow overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) still seems to be pre-v2.4.0 since it is described in [this](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication) post dated before the release of v2.4.0, but seems to use a different process than that outlined in that first code snippet. (It also seems that Google's process has changed a bit since the guide was published, moving from a Google+ sign in to a new Google Sign-In system.)

**In summary, what is the accepted way of logging in my end user via Google and authenticating via Cognito (for future AWS API calls) using the latest AWS iOS SDK (v2.4.7)?**

Here is my current attempt. First, in my app delegate, I initialize the AWS service as described in the guide:

```
// AWS setup
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId:"us-east-1:<REDACTED>")
let serviceConfig = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfig
```

Then, when the Google Sign-In process is complete, I attempt to use the id token to authenticate with Cognito. The `user` in the following snippet is the `GIDGoogleUser` returned by a successful Google Sign-In. I have verified the Google Sign-In is working and I have a valid id token.

```
let getIdInput = AWSCognitoIdentityGetIdInput()
getIdInput.logins = [ "accounts.google.com" : user.authentication.idToken ]
getIdInput.identityPoolId = "us-east-1:<REDACTED>"
getIdInput.accountId = "<REDACTED>"
AWSCognitoIdentity.defaultCognitoIdentity().getId(getIdInput).continueWithBlock{ (task: AWSTask?) -> AnyObject? in
    if task?.error == nil {
        let result = task?.result as! AWSCognitoIdentityGetIdResponse
        let input = AWSCognitoIdentityGetCredentialsForIdentityInput()
        input.identityId = result.identityId
        AWSCognitoIdentity.defaultCognitoIdentity().getCredentialsForIdentity(input)
    } else {
    }
    return nil
}
```

The logs give

```
Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.
```

This is not necessarily incorrect (it is true that I don't allow unauthenticated access for this pool), but is not what I expected, since the Google token which I passed should have authenticated the user. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I was early enough in the development process that I could switch backend services. After some quick research, I've tentatively switched to [Firebase by Google](http://firebase.google.com/). I managed to implement in 30 minutes what I had previously struggled with for 6 hours using AWS. I can't say for sure if it's a good alternate for all AWS Cognito use cases, but it looks like it will work for me. Definitely worth checking out if you're just getting started.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question related to Cognito. You need to set the logins in  AWSCognitoIdentityGetCredentialsForIdentityInput as well. 
Additionally for simplification you can use the high level SDK for Cognito.
Examples can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html